# Make a JFrame full screen in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, jframe, fullscreen, kiosk

I would like a JFrame to fill the entire screen and also cover the task bar at the top and bottom of the screen. Here is my the code to set the JFrame dimensions and properties;

```
f.setUndecorated(true);
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
f.setUndecorated(true);
f.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
f.setSize(java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
f.setResizable(false);
f.setVisible(true);
```

It works OK in Windows and covers the start bar, but in Ubuntu the task bars are always displayed on top of the Java GUI.

It may be a setting in Ubuntu that means the task bars are always on top. If so how can I disable this.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are talking about full screen exclusive mode? I am pretty sure that in Ubuntu Precise you cannot get rid of taskbar on top or bottom, but you can hide the doc, if that is what you mean. To do that though, it is in the system settings and, to my knowledge, there is no java code that will change system settings in Ubuntu.
All of that aside, you may want to look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/exclusivemode.html), especially the programming tips.
In addition, you may want to have these lines of code in your program:

```
GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice device = env.getDefaultScreenDevice();
device.setFullScreenWindow(f);
```

This should make your JFrame full screen exclusive. This will most definitely work on macs and windows to make java programs full screen exclusive.

If you are still curious about the task bars look at [this](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2295814). I hope it helps.